# CakePHP Tree behavior and parent_id field being varchar

Tags: cakephp-2.1

Using the tree behavior in CakePHP, can parent_id field be of varchar? I have some existing records but their ids (employee_id) is of varchar. The parent_id field would represent the supervisor_id field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory it should not be a problem, but it will be much slower than an integer key on big joins or SELECTS. This would drastically affect your application's performance.
You could try to put an constraint there though.

You should also check the code of the Tree behaviour just to be sure there isn't something to prevent it from working.

Alternatively if these varchar fields are all numbers check if you could convert them to int.

Comment: Yes some of the employee IDs are strings. I tried it and it took nearly 45 mins to process 1600+ records. I also looked in the Tree Behaviour code, didn't see much I could hack. Thanks though.

Comment: What database management system are you using? There usually is no need to process the records manually. If all foreign keys are strings representing integers you should be able to convert the field. Also you could "convert" all string ids to consecutive numbers via a DB Procedure or a server-side script. All major [DBs have Control Structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow), so it should not be a big problem to regenerate consecutive integer keys for all records and change all ids in all affected tables.